# Validación de datos en un UPDATE - PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un crud y estoy teniendo problemas para validar los datos del UPDATE, básicamente yo tomo el campo ISBN para verificar que no se inserte dos veces el mismo libro, En el INSERT logre crear la validación correctamente la parte que dice "$sql = "SELECT * FROM libro WHERE isbn='$isbn'";" hasta el primer else, pero en el update no logre validar que al editar no se coloque un isbn ya existente, en resumen no deberia tener dos ISBN iguales pero si hago un UPDATE puedo terminar con dos en la base datos.

Este es el codigo del INSERT

```
<?php
require_once("../clase/conexion.php");
$con=conexion();
       $libro=$_POST["nombre"];
       $isbn=$_POST["isbn"];
       $autor=$_POST["id_autor"];
       $editorial=$_POST["id_editorial"];
       $año=$_POST["anio_edicion"];
       $tipo=$_POST["tipo"];
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM libro WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            header('Location:lista.php?error');
       }else{
    $sql2="INSERT INTO libro(nombre,isbn,id_autor,id_editorial,anio_edicion,id_tipo) 
            VALUES ('$libro','$isbn','$autor','$editorial','$año','$tipo')";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
    mysqli_error($con);
    if($query){
        header('refresh:0;url=lista.php?registrado');   
    }else{
        header('Location:lista.php?error');
    }
}
?>
```

Este es el codigo del UPDATE

```
<?php
require_once("../clase/conexion.php");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$con=conexion();
       $libro=$_POST["nombre"];
       $isbn=$_POST["isbn"];
       $autor=$_POST["id_autor"];
       $editorial=$_POST["id_editorial"];
       $año=$_POST["anio_edicion"];
       $tipo=$_POST["tipo"];
    $sql="UPDATE libro 
    SET nombre='$libro',isbn='$isbn',id_autor='$autor',id_editorial='$editorial',anio_edicion='$año',id_tipo='$tipo' WHERE idlibro='$_REQUEST[idlibro]'";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($query){
        header('refresh:0;url=lista.php?editado');   
    }else{
        header('Location:lista.php?erroredit');
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, si usted define como campo único el ISBN en su tabla no tendría ese problema que el ISBN se repitiera, solo tendría que manejar el error cuando intente actualizar un ISBN ya existente.

Pero como creo que no es el caso, la validación mas básica que puede hacer es la misma que hace en el insert, hacer el UPDATE cuando compruebe que el ISBN que esta mandando en su formulario de actualizar no se encuentra en la tabla.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM libro WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        header('Location:lista.php?error');
   }else{
        $sql="UPDATE libro SET nombre='$libro',isbn='$isbn',id_autor='$autor',id_editorial='$editorial',anio_edicion='$año',id_tipo='$tipo' WHERE idlibro='$_REQUEST[idlibro]'";
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y funciona perfecto, el unico problema que al guardar sin modificar nada, me lo toma tambien como error pero no es un problema, muchas gracias